# ament_python: Package doesn't explicitly install a marker in the package index

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to implement a pure-Python ROS 2 package with ament_python.

When building, I get the following warning:

> WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.task.ament_python.build:Package 'foobar' doesn't explicitly install a marker in the package index (colcon-ros currently does it implicitly but that fallback will be removed in the future)

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any information about this.  What is this "marker" about and how do I install it correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367328/ament_python:-package-doesn%27t-explicitly-install-a-marker-in-the-package-index/) by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 382 on 2020-12-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "package index" is part of the ament resource index. It's how ROS 2 tools figure out what packages are installed. [Read about the design of it is here](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/2c69087f74b20a797cd1e502f3f2f3f7c407be22/ament_cmake_core/doc/resource_index.md#file-system-index-layout).

Colcon currently creates this file automatically for `ament_python` packages, but it won't in the future. Packages will need to install a marker file themselves. This is just a blank file in `share/ament_index/resource_index/packages/foobar` where `foobar` is the name of your package.

The usual way to install this is to copy an empty file using the `data_files` argument. ([actual example in ros2topic](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/blob/f6c4a5b05d172f8156645b8fcf8bd2dfa23e7bb2/ros2topic/setup.py#L12-L13)).

Your package layout might look like:

```
mypythonpkg/
├── mypythonpkg
│   └── __init__.py
├── package.xml
├── resource
│   └── mypythonpkg
└── setup.py
```

And your `setup.py` might have

```
package_name = 'mypythonpkg'

setup(
    # ...
    data_files=[
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
    ],
    # ...
)
```

If you're interested in why Colcon's behavior is changing, there's more info here:

- https://github.com/ament/ament_index/issues/33
- https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/pull/74
- https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/pull/79
- https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/pull/82

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2